# how do I execute a task when sbt update dependencies?

Tags: sbt

I'm writing a sbt plugin for bower (https://github.com/MasseGuillaume/sbt-bower).

I would like to start a task when sbt update or start. For example, after updating ivy dependencies, update frontend dependencies.

I was thinking depending on the update task, but it wont map.

```
override lazy val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Bower) (Seq (
    install <<= update map( _ => installTask )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally, make your task a dependency of where it is used.  It sounds
>   like the results of your resolution should be added to
>   managedResources, so you should append the results of the custom
>   frontend update task to managedResources and it will be automatically
>   run whenever someone needs resources (like package, run, ...).  Make
>   sure that the update task checks if it needs to do work, since it will
>   be run everytime those other tasks are run.
>
> --Mark Harrah